CENTOS linux SElinux mls mode.. root user.. root user does not have permissions
root user does not have permissions. SElinux mls mode is active
The system is completely out of control. Information cannot be accessed.
file structure and permissions are disabled..

drwxr-xr-x. 7 fezag fezag 4096 Nov 24 14:26 fezag
d?????????? ? ?     ?        ?            ? vmail
[root@design home]# cd fezag
[root@design fezag]# ll
ls: cannot access 'postfixdovecot': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'mariadbBackup': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'PLOT16.tar.gz': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'html': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? html
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? mariadbBackup
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? PLOT16.tar.gz
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? postfixdovecot
[root@design fezag]# cd html
-bash: cd: html: Permission denied
[root@design fezag]# will this fix?

